# How can I create multiple search fields with single query? [PHP/HTML]

Tags: php, html

I am using an API curl method to obtain JSON data, then inserting it into an HTML formatted table for my web app.

My needs have changed slightly and I require to now search for multiple ticket numbers in a single search. Here is what I have currently..

```
 <form action="http://-withheld-/shop/ticket.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>

    <button type="submit">Search</button><br>
```

I have tried adding more fields but to no avail.

ie)

```
<input type="text" name="id1" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>
<input type="text" name="id2" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>
<input type="text" name="id3" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>
```

Oh and also, here is the php portion of my code, which currently works in obtaining a single ticket ID upon search.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }
```

I've attempted to add more fields with my above HTML code and this code below:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id1'];
$id = $_GET['id2'];
$id = $_GET['id3'];

        }
```

etc etc. If anyone could help me with this I'd be very appreciative. I know this is a VERY basic question but I was unable to find any specifics in regard to querying multiple searches using the $_GET method. Everything I've found has been in relation to a MYSQL query.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: If you are changing your fields to id1, id2, id3 and only checking if 'id' is set, you're going to run into issues if you no longer have an id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form:

```
<form action="http://-withheld-/shop/ticket.php" method="GET">
 <input type="text" name="id1" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>
 <input type="text" name="id2" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>
 <input type="text" name="id3" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"><br>

<button type="submit">Search</button><br>
```

Collect the form data and querying the json data:

```
if(isset($_GET['id1'])) {
$id1 = $_GET['id1'];
$url1 = 'http://-withheld-/api/v1/tickets/'.$id1.'?api_key=0f8797897-ba73-40bb-9b74-366ef‌​03c2cbf'; 
// Initiate curl 
$ch1 = curl_init(); 
// Disable SSL verification 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
// Will return the response, if false it print the response 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
// Set the url 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,$url1); 
// Execute 
$result1=curl_exec($ch1); 
// Closing 
curl_close($ch1); 
// Will dump a beauty json :3 
$jsonObj1 = json_decode($result1);
}
if(isset($_GET['id2'])) {
$id2 = $_GET['id2'];
$url2 = 'http://-withheld-/api/v1/tickets/'.$id2.'?api_key=0f8797897-ba73-40bb-9b74-366ef‌​03c2cbf'; 
// Initiate curl 
$ch2 = curl_init(); 
// Disable SSL verification 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
// Will return the response, if false it print the response 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
// Set the url 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,$url2); 
// Execute 
$result2=curl_exec($ch2); 
// Closing 
curl_close($ch2); 
// Will dump a beauty json :3 
$jsonObj2 = json_decode($result2);
}
}
if(isset($_GET['id3'])) {
$id3 = $_GET['id3'];
$url3 = 'http://-withheld-/api/v1/tickets/'.$id3.'?api_key=0f8797897-ba73-40bb-9b74-366ef‌​03c2cbf';
// Initiate curl 
$ch3 = curl_init(); 
// Disable SSL verification 
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
// Will return the response, if false it print the response 
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
// Set the url 
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL,$url3); 
// Execute 
$result3=curl_exec($ch3); 
// Closing 
curl_close($ch3); 
// Will dump a beauty json :3 
$jsonObj3 = json_decode($result3);
}
}
```

Then displaying the results:

```
if(isset($jsonObj1)){
foreach ($jsonObj1->{'tickets'} as $ticket1) { 
echo '<tr>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'id'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'number'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'customer_business_then_name'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'subject'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'created_at'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'status'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'problem_type'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket1->{'updated_at'}.'</td>'; echo '<td><a href="'.$link_addr.'">View</a></td>'; echo '<html></tr></html>';
}
}

if(isset($jsonObj2)){
foreach ($jsonObj2->{'tickets'} as $ticket2) { 
echo '<tr>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'id'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'number'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'customer_business_then_name'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'subject'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'created_at'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'status'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'problem_type'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket2->{'updated_at'}.'</td>'; echo '<td><a href="'.$link_addr.'">View</a></td>'; echo '<html></tr></html>';
}
}

if(isset($jsonObj3)){
foreach ($jsonObj3->{'tickets'} as $ticket3) { 
echo '<tr>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'id'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'number'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'customer_business_then_name'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'subject'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'created_at'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'status'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'problem_type'}.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$ticket3->{'updated_at'}.'</td>'; echo '<td><a href="'.$link_addr.'">View</a></td>'; echo '<html></tr></html>';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response! I tried this code as you specified:


Sadly, it returns an empty table.

I'm NOT using an SQL database as I specified in my question above. I'm using a CURL from an API.

Comment: `$url = 'http://-withheld-/api/v1/tickets/'.$id.'?api_key=0f8797897-ba73-40bb-9b74-366ef03c2cbf';

  //  Initiate curl
  $ch = curl_init();
  // Disable SSL verification
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  // Will return the response, if false it print the response
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // Set the url
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  // Execute
  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  // Closing
  curl_close($ch);

  // Will dump a beauty json :3
  $jsonObj = json_decode($result);
  ?>
`

Comment: What way are you displaying the result in your html table?

Comment: It's an HTML table.

`code:
echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'id'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'number'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'customer_business_then_name'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'subject'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'created_at'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'status'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'problem_type'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'updated_at'}.'</td>';
  echo '<td><a href="'.$link_addr.'">View</a></td>';
  echo '<html></tr></html>';`

Comment: Where is the $ticket variable coming from?

Comment: Still giving me a blank table.

I wonder if this has anything to do with it?

// Set the url
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  // Execute
  $result=curl_exec($ch);

I see that the $url1, $url2, $url3 won't be used in place of $url.

Also, the formatting in these comments is absurd.

Comment: We just need to bridge the gap between $jsonObj and $ticket, which should then work

Comment: ticket variable is setup like this:
foreach ($jsonObj->{'tickets'} as $ticket) {

Comment: Tried the latest edit. Still throwing me a blank html table :( Do you have skype? I could share screen with you and run through my application with you.

Comment: What IDE are you using? I'm getting tons of "expected ')' " around line 58 right after your "as" statements. Phpstorm does not like this code and when I test it on my live server I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)

Comment: just noticed made 1 slight mistake on the second json decode - $url1 was ment to be $url2 when setting the url

Comment: Still getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)

Comment: Is this for a website?

Comment: Yes it is for a website

Comment: Yeah I missed the "foreach" statement, that should work now sorry

Comment: If it doesn't work this time set the computer on fire

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: lol, believe me. If I could I would at this point. I really appreciate all the effort you're putting into helping me!

Comment: Have you copied everything exactly as above?

Comment: yes sir, copied exactly. Only thing I've done is removed your extra braces } as it seems you've doubled up on them in between the if statements. Exact error I'm getting is this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - 1 warning for EACH if statement that contains foreach

Comment: Yes the first } is the closing brace for the foreach statement and the second is for the if statement

Comment: Even so, its copied exactly. Still getting that error.

Comment: Ok let me just make one more edit, the reason you are getting that error is because the foreach statement is being fed an empty variable

Comment: Ok, please let me know when I can test :)

Comment: Try it now, I changed the if($jsonObj1 != NULL) to if(isset($jsonObj1)) hopefully that will sort it out :)

Comment: after copying + pasting the exact code (only changing the withheld $URL) I am getting this error STILL. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: My skype: NaturedOne

Comment: *** (only changing the withheld $URL) *** above comment

Comment: and so begins my decent into madness.

Comment: where are the experts when you need them?

Comment: No idea. I'm definitely not one of them.

Comment: Try echoing out each variable until you find the error, I've been looking at this all day and it really should be working! the code is spot on..

Comment: Please see my edits, maybe your html form was wrong?

Comment: All of the PHP code should be on the same page, i.e the result display page, I would put the part that collects the form data and queries the json data at the very top of the document in PHP tags, then lower down the document after the <body> tag where you want to display the results, place the code that will display the results in more PHP tags

Comment: Then you will need to debug, I can do it for you for a fee if you wish